# How to monitor an application (Smartcard) access

Tags: windows, smartcard, software-design

This is my first post so please bear with me, will i get use to the posting requirements.

I need help finding out when i insert a smartcard (on Windows 64bit machine), what it then access in the background. I have tried using process monitor, process explorer and TCP View. These didn't provide me with what i needed which is to be able to see ports, registry keys, background network access and so on.I need something that will allow me to activate it to observe what happens when i use a smartcard. The idea is that a smartcard is inserted and then it looks at certain registry keys and also checks via an connection various URL's, ports to ensure access is granted. The problem is the software we have installed hasn't put the registry keys where they should be so i can't change them, and these are what i really need to get at. I have also tried searching the registry keys for a value one would be logged under and i can't seem to find it that way either.

I use to have a piece of software years ago that provided it, was a listener of some sort, but i can't think of it for the life of me what it is called. If anyone can point me in the direction of what i need to be thinking off i would be so grateful!

If i need to be clearer please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Requests for software recommendations are likely to be deleted. However, you fail to say what platform you need this for. Anyway, a Windows guess is you want one of the "Windows Sysinternals" tools.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a smartcard accesses nothing on its own. I'm aware, that Windows might look up the ATR in the registry in order to provide a "friendly card name", but if absent no harm is done except not having the friendly card name.

Any actions like internet request are more likely to be associated with a software tool called *Service Provider*, which knows, what commands to send for this specific card in order to perform actions like:

- User authentication
- Signature computation

Significant knowledge concerning the specific card is required, so entering some registry entries is far from sufficient. If the card contains a certificate, some software may try to verify the certificate chain or ensure, that the key was not revoked, but this is also not initiated by the card.

Comment: Thanks guidot, i know the certifcates and have them. Basically we have two instances, one is LIVE and the other is DEP. I am trying to get the original install process that was perform and the files associated to see if that will shed any light on the location of the reg keys, etc. So what i am trying to do is find the reg keys so i can point it from the LIVE to DEP. We use a piece of software called Identity Agent for the Smartcards and these are the reg keys i require, but when using the monitoring i cant see which reg keys are used and i have search all the reg keys for keys i know to exist